# How to fetch specific cell data from table in Angularjs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I want to get data "Crab" from this table:

```
Sushi Roll   FishType   Taste Level
Cali Roll    Crab            2
Philly       Tuna            4
Rainbow      Variety         6
Tiger        Eel             7
```

Below is code which retrieves data in the last row  but I need to fetch data from row 2 column 2 (Crab)

```
var rows = element.all(by.repeater('roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchFish'));
//var rows = element.all(by.repeater('alert in alerts'));
var row = rows.last();
var rowElems = row.all(element(by.tagName('td')));
console.log(row.get(0).getText());
```

Below is the Outer html

```
<span ng-show="sortType == 'fish' &amp;&amp; !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down ng-hide"></span>
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchFish">
        <td class="ng-binding">Tiger</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Eel</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">7</td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: I don't see anything Angular here...

Comment: It contains ng-repeat element

Comment: your sample doesn't make sense.  did you copy the angular source or did you copy the output from an angular page?

Comment: So if you're creating this table with data in your controller, why do you want to get that data through the DOM?  Why not just access the data from the same source you used to populate the table?

Comment: I am testing the application using Protractor, so i need to validate the data in the cells.

Comment: so then wouldn't `rows[1]` be the second row, then using that to get `rowElems`, your text would be in `rowElems[1]`... is that what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: actually, it is probably `rows[0]`, since you suggest you want `Crab` which is on the *first* row (the headers don't count, since you are finding by repeater)

Comment: Yes, i am  getting "Type error : invalid locator"  if am trying to find using by.repeater

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.get(index)`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) where `index` is 0-based:

```
var rows = element.all(by.repeater('roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchFish'));
var row = rows.get(1);
var rowElems = row.all(element(by.tagName('td')));

console.log(rowElems.get(1).getText());
```

Comment: I am getting "Type error : invalid locator" as error , Consider in the following url (https://hello-angularjs.appspot.com/searchtable) i want to fetch number of employees in  second company